# How do i add custom tag option in custom wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, tags

See here is no tags box how can I add a tag box in the right panel please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are just a taxonomy type so you can create a new taxonomy for your page post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_tags_for_pages_taxonomy', 500, 0);


function create_tags_for_pages_taxonomy() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Tag' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tag:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Tags' ),
  );    

// Now register the taxonomy

  register_taxonomy('page_tags',array('release'), array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),
  ));

}
```

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: in `functions.php`

Comment: Aah, I did not see that you have a custom post type called `release`. I've updated my answer to change it post type in second parameter of `register_taxonomy` from page to release.